# ErrorException Undefined array key 7 on Laravel Excel when import or upload excel file

Tags: excel, laravel, import, undefined

I just doing project import excel using laravel.
But there is an error when *import / upload file excel* and for web page can open and work.

> ErrorException
> Undefined array key 7

```
  public function model(array $row)

{

    return new Dso([

        'id_dso' => $row[1],

        'id_rso' => $row[2],

        'id_focus' => $row[3],

        'id_wilayah' => $row[4],

        'id_grup_wilayah' => $row[5],

        'nama_dso' => $row[6],

        'status' => $row[7],

    ]);

}
```

and my table on database format is

```html
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| Field           | Type                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                         |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| id              | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment                |
| id_dso          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| id_rso          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| id_focus        | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| id_wilayah      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| id_grup_wilayah | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| nama_dso        | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| created_by      | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| created_date    | timestamp           | NO   |     | current_timestamp() | on update current_timestamp() |
| modified_by     | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| modified_date   | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL                |                               |
| status          | tinyint(1)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| created_at      | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL                |                               |
| updated_at      | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL                |                               |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
14 rows in set (0.009 sec)
```

and my data sample is

[Import data Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkiYN.png)

I'm using laravel 8.6 and my datbase is MariaDb.

Comment: is $row an array with 7 items ? in this case it is 0-indexed  ($row[0] ... $row[6])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array starts with index **0**.

So start from `$row[0]` until `$row[6]`

The key `status` will be `$row[6]` in your case.

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    return new Dso([
        'id_dso' => $row[0],
        'id_rso' => $row[1],
        'id_focus' => $row[2],
        'id_wilayah' => $row[3],
        'id_grup_wilayah' => $row[4],
        'nama_dso' => $row[5],
        'status' => $row[6],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry is my explanation is unclear. I mean is happen when I import excel, for web page is can open

Answer (score 1):

Please start your array $row index from $row[0] instead of $row[1] as given as under

```
public function model(array $row)

{

    return new Dso([

        'id_dso' => $row[0],

        'id_rso' => $row[1],

        'id_focus' => $row[2],

        'id_wilayah' => $row[3],

        'id_grup_wilayah' => $row[4],

        'nama_dso' => $row[5],

        'status' => $row[6],

    ]);

}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function model(array $row)
    
    {
    
        return new Dso([
    
            'id_dso' => $row[1],
    
            'id_rso' => $row[2],
    
            'id_focus' => $row[3],
    
            'id_wilayah' => $row[4],
    
            'id_grup_wilayah' => $row[5],
    
            'nama_dso' => $row[6],
    
            'status' => ($row[7]) ? $row[7] : ' ',
    
        ]);
    
    }
```

Comment: I was tried, but still same error. 
This happen when import excel document for web page is okay no problem